# How to use MediaColumns#IS_PENDING to save Base64 encoded image to Gallery

Tags: android

An activity in my app represents an image as a `Base64 encoded string`.

I am tossing out `saveImage` for `MediaColumns#IS_PENDING` to save the image to the device.

> **insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, String name, String description)**
>   This method was deprecated in API level 29. inserting of images should be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer control over lifecycle.

How can one save this Base64 encoded string to the image gallery with `MediaColumns#IS_PENDING`?

Here is my ongoing attempt:

```
private Uri saveImage(final Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "imageBase64String=" + imageBase64String);
    Log.d(TAG, "getDisplayName()=" + getDisplayName());

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, getDisplayName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_INTERNAL);
    Uri item = resolver.insert(collection, values);

    try ( ParcelFileDescriptor pfd =
                    resolver.openFileDescriptor(item, "w", null)) {
        // Write data into the pending image.
    } catch ( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Now that we're finished, release the "pending" status, and allow other apps
    // to view the image.

    values.clear();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
    resolver.update(item, values, null, null);

    return item;
}
```

Currently I get

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing to internal storage is not supported.

and I am running the code on an emulator.

I simply want to save the `Base64 encoded string` to either the `Gallery` or the `Downloads`.

I must also return the `URI` of the image.

**edit**

A possibility is to convert the String to a `BitMap` and save the bitmap to the device.